# Is there a ready-made CSS I can download to style my forms in Symfony?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms

I just defined some forms in /lib/form/doctrine/  But the form elements currently don't have any CSS formatting.

Is there a default stylesheet that I can quickly copy/paste to style the forms, error messages, etc.?

Comment: The admin generator has nice markup and css. You could inerhit from there css and be happy :)

Comment: Ah yeah, the CSS for the admin worked great. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used Symfony's CSS from the admin. It was exactly what I was looking for - good results with minimal effort. Thanks for the suggestion cuhuak.

Answer (score 1):

It's not out of the box for Symfony but [Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) is a nice CSS framework, and when I used symfony 1.4, it used to color automatically the errors (I don't know if they changed the class names and stuff).
It's a bit heavy, but it ensures a solid structure if you use it for your development.

Comment: I tried Blueprint CSS (copy/pasted), and it didn't work as well the Symfony's CSS from the admin. Thanks for the suggestion though.